# Disable math.h crap when working with cmath

Tags: c++, c, namespaces, math.h, cmath

I had a problem previously because of functions being overloaded without `std::`. And the curse is still happening every now and then because I don't use `using namespace std;`.

[Removing using namespace std causes the program to get crap results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740628/removing-using-namespace-std-causes-the-program-to-get-crap-results)

Is there a way to disable all those non-std functions that come from c and only work with c++ functions under the namespace `std` (without having to use `using namespace std;`)?

In other words: I want to get an error if I use `sin()` rather than `std::sin()` so that I won't do that mistake. Of c
ourse, not only for sin, but every function that has a conflict with `math.h`.

Comment: Don't you get an error if you omit `math.h` and use `sin` without `std::` ?

Comment: Why not prepend with `std::`?

Comment: @cnicutar: The problem is that `<cmath>` and friends may (or may not) dump some or all of the functions into the global namespace. The "crap" in the linked question came from accidentally calling `::abs(int)` instead of `std::abs(double)`.

Comment: @JesseGood: Because sometimes we make mistakes. That's why the question is asking how to make it an error if we make that particular mistake.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Oh good to know. I thought `cmath` puts everything in `std::`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I see now, although I think typing `std::` should come as second nature.

Comment: It's all about doing a mistake! a mistake could get you to debug for hours because there's no specific way to search for it but recheck the whole code! It's so nasty!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Agreed it is a very real problem this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123631/float-to-double-misinterpretation-g) yesterday was due to not using the `std` version and it took a while by S) standards for people to figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do that. The rule is that `#include <math.h>` puts all of the names into the global namespace, and is also allowed to put them into `std::`. Similarly, `#include <cmath>` puts all the names into `std::`, and is allowed to also put them into the global namespace. The reason for allowing the extraneous namespaces is simply that the pure versions are unimplementable in general without major surgery to existing libraries that may not even be under the control of the C++ compiler folks.

Answer (score 7):

Gather all function declarations from math.h into `namespace neveruse`, and say `using namespace neveruse`. Now all references to unqualified `sin` will be ambiguous.

Comment: Wouldn't this... like mess the standard library? How can I know if this won't affect something else somewhere else?

Comment: You are allowed to declare any function in your own namespace. There's no conflict with anything. The only way it can affect stuff is by generating compilation errors.